# How do I define a hierarchy for a generic json-spray parser?

Tags: scala, spray-json

We have an API that always has a `total-count` and `entities` in the response, but the `entities` are of different types.  What I'm trying to do is make the parsing & converting to case-classes more generic.

So trying with the following types

```
case class StandardReturn[A](
    `total-count`: Double,
    entities: List[A]
)

case class System(
    id: String,
    name: String
)
```

And the following example:

```
object SystemProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val systemFormat: RootJsonFormat[System] = 
    jsonFormat2(System)
  implicit def entityFormat[A: JsonFormat] =
    jsonFormat(StandardReturn.apply[A], "total-count", "entities")
}
import SystemProtocol._

val response = """{
  "total-count": 10,
  "entities": [
    { "id": "1", "name": "me" }
  ]
}"""

class Example {
  def transform[A: JsonReader](entityString: String) =
    entityString.parseJson
      .convertTo[A]
      .entities  // Where I'm running into trouble
}
object Example {
  val transformed = new Example().transform[StandardReturn[System]](response)
}
Example.transformed
```

Which is understandably giving me

```
Error:(34, 42) value entities is not a member of type parameter A
entityString.parseJson.convertTo[A].entities  // Where I'm running into trouble
                                    ^
```

How would I set up the case classes / types so that `transform` could be assured that `entities` will always exist after converting to type `A` (where `A` is `StandardReturn[A]`)?  I'm not too familiar with scala's type system, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Code, the type parameter `A` has no bounds except the context bound to JsonReader (an implicit parameter of type `JsonReader[A]`). Therefore, as you already mentioned, `A` could be anything, so you can't call the `entities` method. If you convert to `StandardReturn[A]` instead of just `A`, this problem is resolved.

```
def transform[A: JsonReader](entityString: String) =
  entityString.parseJson
    .convertTo[StandardReturn[A]] <- just convert to what you actually want
    .entities
```

Additionally, you have to replace the type parameter in `new Example().transform[StandardReturn[System]](response)` by just `System` instead of `StandardReturn[System]`, as the method above was changed.

The compiler now needs an implicit parameter of type `JsonReader[StandardFormat[System]]`. But in the implicit scope, there is only the `systemFormat` of type `JsonReader[System]` (in `SystemProtocol`). The compiler does not give up yet: he tries to find an implicit conversion from `JsonReader[System]` to `JsonReader[StandardFormat[System]]`, and that is just the method `entityFormat` you defined. Yeah!

One last remark: You could further simplify the method `entityFormat` if you replace `jsonFormat(StandardReturn.apply[A], "total-count", "entities")` by `jsonFormat2(StandardReturn.apply[A])`, as noted in the [documentation](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes).